# List does not exist with url

Tags: list

I have a list which I programmatically want to access and query it.
But when I write

`SPList list=web.Lists[listname];`

(Where listname is stored in a variable)

It gives a error

> List does not exist with the url

Even though the list exists.

Comment: Can you debug and enumerate through `web.Lists` and see if it actually is there?

Comment: Don't forget to put "" in the listname. ["Listname"]

Comment: Make sure that the security context account has access to the list root.

Comment: Actually it was a space issue.A space was appended at the end of the list name and hence it was not able to find the list.Using trim solved the problem.                              Thank you everyone.